# Category and Sub category in one column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

How we can show `category` and `subcategory` in one column in sql. Both columns are present in same table `TableA`.

Example: `TableA`

```
--------------------------------------
| category |  subcategory |  Values  |
--------------------------------------
| Bird     |  parrot       |     5   |
| Bird     |  pigeon       |     10  |
| Animal   |  lion         |     2   |
| Animal   |  Tiger        |     5   |
--------------------------------------
```

Output table :

```
-------------------
| NEW    |  Value  |
--------------------
| Bird   |   15    |
| parrot |   5     |
| Piegon |   10    |
| Animal |   7     |
| lion   |   2     |
| Tiger  |   5     |
--------------------
```

In the output, New is a column where I want both category and sub category.

Sample Query to generate data:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
catgory nvarchar(200),
sub_category nvarchar(200),
[values] nvarchar(200),
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('Bird','parrot',5)
INSERT INTO #TEMP  VALUES ('Bird','pigeon',10)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('Animal','lion',2)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('Animal','Tiger',5)
```

Where the logic is:

I want category and sub category together, Where category should show the sum of all sub category values and should be in order as I have output table

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a proper database tag.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have provided sample data if you know please let me know..

Comment: @pinkyadhikari database? MySql? MSSQL?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale SQL server

Comment: @pinkyadhikari what is the logic behind that expected result?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i want category and sub category together , Where category should show sum of all sub category values and should be in order as i have given in example

Answer (score 0):

**Try this.**

```
select new, [values] from (select catgory, sub_category as 'new', [values] from temp 
union all 
select catgory, catgory as 'new', sum([values]) from temp group by catgory) order by catgory
```

**Output:**

```
    new values
   -------------
    parrot  5
    pigeon  10
    Bird    15
    lion    2
    lion    2
    Tiger   5
    Animal  9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT category,value FROM yourtable WHERE category IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT subcategory, value FROM yourtable WHERE subcategory IS NOT NULL    
)
SELECT Company as new, value FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select category, sum(values) values from table group by category
union
select subcategory, values from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Table structure:

Id, name, parentcategoryId

1, animals, null

2, fish, 1

Example mssql:

```
Select name,  subcats = STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + NAME
            FROM category as cat1 where cat1.parentcategoryId = cat. parentcategoryId
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')  from category as cat where parentcategoryId = null
```

Preview:

Name, subcats

Animals, fish

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cte` :

```
with cte as (
     select t.*, 
            dense_rank() over (order by category) as seq, 
            sum([values]) over (partition by category) as sums
     from table t
)

select t.cat as new, (case when cat_name = 'category' then sums else c.[values] end) as Value
from cte c cross apply
     ( values ('category', category), ('sub_category', sub_category) ) t(cat_name, cat)
order by seq, (case when cat_name = 'category' then 1 else 2 end);
```

Answer (score 0):

Needs UNION ALL after getting the sums with the main table:

```
select 
  case t.sub_category
    when '' then t.category
    else sub_category
  end new,
  t.value
from (
  select category, '' sub_category, sum([values]) value from temp group by category
  union all
  select category, sub_category, [values] value from temp
) t
order by t.category, t.sub_category
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=33a1147d7fc8a62d010794829be7d576).
Results:

```
> new    | value
> :----- | ----:
> Animal |     7
> lion   |     2
> Tiger  |     5
> Bird   |    15
> parrot |     5
> pigeon |    10
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this uses `grouping sets`:

```
select coalesce(subcategory, category) as new, sum(val)
from temp
group by grouping sets ( (category), (subcategory, category))
order by category, subcategory
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a1db135192d2178f4deff8ae44c5eb4c) is a db<>fiddle.